# What's the Rust equivalent return value of a Java function that returns multiple exceptions?

Tags: rust

What's the appropriate return value of a function in Rust which in Java looks like this?

```java
void verify(String input) {
  if (!checkInput(input)) return Exception1("....");
  if (!checkInput2(input)) return Exception2("....");
  if (!checkInput3(input)) return Exception3("....");
}
```

I figure it should be `Result<(), &str>` or `Result<bool, &str>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current state of the art in Rust:

- an `enum` to represent the result, `bool` being the "simplest" one
- an `Option`, to encapsulate the result, and give no detail in case of error
- a `Result<R, E>` to encapsulate either the result or an error

The function you present is a unique challenge, it could be represented either as:

- `Result<(), Error>` with `Error` being whatever you want it to be (`&str` might be too restrictive, or not structured enough)
- `Option<Error>` if you *invert* the function, that is make it look for an error instead of assessing that there is none

Either look fine, `Result<(), Error>` being more easily amenable to `?` and the like.

Comment: Wouldn't `Result<(), CustomError>` be a good fit, where `CustomError` is an Enum with states `Exception1` through `Exception3`? These states could of course contain a string. But this way you could match all the different cases in the caller function.

Comment: @marcusklaas: I would recommend it if you wish to give the callers a chance to recover. As usual, it is much easier, and much less brittle, to access readily available information than to attempt to divine it by parsing a string, etc... Given the low cost of an `enum` (just one more word), it's cheap enough not to burden overmuch people who do not care about it.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: whatever you want it to be. It can be as simple as `&str` or as complicated as a custom `enum` with various structured information depending on the error case.

Answer (score 3):

While you could have `Result<(), &'static str>`, using an enum for the different error possibilities is generally going to be superior. You can then use string formatting (a `std::fmt::Display` implementation) to turn it into a nice error message. Something like this:

```
use std::fmt;

enum Error {
    FirstProblem,
    SecondNuisance,
    ThirdBadThing,
}

impl fmt::Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str(match *self {
            Error::FirstProblem => "first problem",
            Error::SecondNuisance => "second nuisance",
            Error::ThirdBadThing => "third bad thing",
        })
    }
}

fn verify(input: &str) -> Result<(), Error> {
    if !check_input(input) { return Err(Error::FirstProblem); }
    if !check_input2(input) { return Err(Error::SecondNuisance); }
    if !check_input3(input) { return Err(Error::ThirdBadThing); }
    Ok(())
}
```

Semantically, `Result` is very good; your `verify` function can either signal that everything is OK, or that an error occurred. If there is an error, indicating what it is is worthwhile—hence the `Error` type. If everything is OK, is there extra information that can be conveyed? If it is merely a question of “it worked”, then your `bool` would presumably always be `true`, which kind of negates the purpose of it. Therefore having the `Ok` variant be `()` makes sense.

Comment: why not just `&str` instead of `&'static str`?

Comment: Because string literals have a static lifetime (lifetime of entire program): http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: well, `&str` has an anonymous lifetime; it *may* be `'static`, but it is not guaranteed to be. A string literal will coerce to any `'_` in `&'_ str`, but if you’re storing it anywhere, `&'static str` makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Interesting, I get some compile errors when I try to run this code. @ChrisMorgan have there been some changes to the `std::fmt` crate. First, I had to change `impl fmt::Show` to `impl fmt::Display.` Also looks like there is no function `write` defined for `std::fmt::Formatter` and might need to use `write_str` instead. Just wanted to check if those changes would be correct.

Comment: Say, @ChrisMorgan should there be a `#[derive(Debug)]` above the `Error` enum? I just got bit by that issue, haha. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994176/result-has-no-method-called-unwrap#30994296 . I tried to compile the code above in rust playground, but the `check_input` function is not implemented so the code does not compile. I suppose I can submit this update and you can approve it if you think it is valid.

Comment: @krishnab: `Debug` is only _necessary_ if you do something that needs it, such as attempting to unwrap a result with that as the error type. `Error` itself doesn’t depend on `Debug`. This code is only a demonstration of the concept, but in real life _all_ types should implement `Debug`.