# Result has no method called "unwrap()"?

Tags: rust

What a strange error:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

struct MyStruct1;
struct Error;

fn get_res() -> Result<(MyStruct1, BTreeMap<String, String>), Error> {
    Err(Error)
}

fn main() {
    let res1 = get_res();
    assert!(res1.is_ok());
    assert_eq!("just for test", res1.unwrap()); //error
}
```

The error is:

```
error: no method named `unwrap` found for type `std::result::Result<(MyStruct1, std::collections::BTreeMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>), Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:38
   |
13 |     assert_eq!("just for test", res1.unwrap()); //error
   |                                      ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `unwrap` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `Error : std::fmt::Debug`
```

Comment: try `assert_eq!(res1.unwrap(),"just for test");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Result type does not implement method in scope named \`unwrap\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787271/result-type-does-not-implement-method-in-scope-named-unwrap)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap), you'll note that it's under a little section called:

```
impl<T, E> Result<T, E> 
    where E: Debug
```

This means the methods in that section *only exist* so long as the given constraints are satisfied.

The only reason `unwrap` wouldn't exist is that `Error` doesn't implement `Debug`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a feature request opened against rustc to explicitly list *why* the methods were not considered when it finds methods with the right name? It might be tough, for common names, though they could be prioritized in some may and limited in number, however this is something I found invaluable in C++ SFINAE since Clang introduced the feature.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I actually [opened one in response to this question](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26516).

Comment: @DK.: I can't comment on it right now, you might want to mention that Clang manages it with SFINAE exclusion on template methods in C++, which is fairly similar (since SFINAE is about culling methods depending on some conditions). This not only means the feature is actually implementable, but may also provide a reference implementation for a would-be implementer.

Comment: Any idea why they didn't implement `unwrap()` for non-`Debug` types?

Comment: @Timmmm I assume this is because they want to include some informative message in the panic! that happens if you try to unwrap() an error- you need Debug to turn the E value into this message.

Comment: So what do you do if you want to `unwrap()` but you didn't define the error type so it's not up to you whether it's Debug? Running into this with `TryInto<usize>`.

Comment: Then I think you're stuck using `if let Ok(t) = t { } else { panic!(); }`

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I regularly do embedded development in environments where `format!(...)` is not available and thought I could just leave this here:

```rust
pub trait DiscreetUnwrap<T, E> {
    fn duwrp(self) -> T;
}

impl<T, E> DiscreetUnwrap<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn duwrp(self) -> T  {
        match self {
            Ok(r) => r,
            Err(_) => {
                panic!("duwrp() failed.")
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Just use `.duwrp()` wherever you use `.unwrap()` and you won't be bothered anymore. You will obviously lose the actual error message, but you could adapt the code to format it properly, if possible (e.g. if you're using `ufmt`).