# Cloning from Vec of Ref Counted times to a vec of object

Tags: rust

I currently I have a `Vec<Rc<Item>>` and I would very much like to have a `Vec<Item>` in which each Rc item is cloned into the new Vec. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the usual `iter().map(...).collect()` pattern for this.  Inside the map, you need to create a clone of the item inside the `Rc` by dereferencing first and then calling `clone()`:

```
let v: Vec<_> = (0..10).map(|_| Rc::new(String::from("a"))).collect();
let v: Vec<_> = v.iter().map(|s| (**s).clone()).collect();
```

The type of `s` in the closure is `&Rc<String>`.  By dereferencing once, you get `Rc<String>`.  By dereferencing again you get a `String`.  The string is implicitly reborrowed for the call to `clone()`, which returns a copy of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid cloning anything, and you only have one reference to each value in the array, then you can just unwrap the `Rc`s:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let strs = vec![Rc::new("aghaj".to_string()); 7];

    println!("{:?}", strs);

    let unwrapped: Vec<_> = strs
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| Rc::try_unwrap(x).unwrap())
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", unwrapped);
}
```

Comment: I get a error saying `no method named "unwrap" found for type "std::result::Result<MyObjectl, std::rc::Rc<Myobject>>" in the current scope`.
This is because unwrap requires the Rc Error to have the Debug trait implemented. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994296/3738647

 the method `unwrap` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:           `std::rc::Rc<ics_channels::ics_channel::Channel> : std::fmt::Debug

Comment: @user373864q that's weird, because it works just fine on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b0512ce5676eaf2bc5c7284b2a2a694e what version of rust are you on?

Comment: 1.29.1
It may because I am using an object instead of a primitive.

Comment: You might be doing it wrong. You don't just call `.unwrap()` on the Rc. You have to do `try_unwrap` first like in my example

Comment: I tried that 

`pub fn get_things (&self) -> Vec<Thing> {

        self.things.into_iter().map(|x| Rc::try_unwrap(x).unwrap()).collect()

}`

Comment: Can you sharea playground link with a reproduction? Maybe then I can help.

Comment: Unwrap needs the contained object to be `Debug` for panic messages