# Move `Var` out from `Arc<Mutex<Var>>`

Tags: multithreading, rust

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

struct Var {}

fn multithreading() -> Var {
    let shared_var = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Var {}));
    /*
    multithreading job
     */

    return *(shared_var.lock().unwrap().deref());
}
```

I'm defining a multi-threading function to operate on `Var` but this function doesn't compile and complaint:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
```

Is there any way to stop the sharing of `shared_var` and return the variable within?

Implementing trait `Copy` for `Var` may also solve the bug, but in my actual use case `Var` is too large to copy that I would prefer any other solution.

Comment: Remember that at the machine code level, moving essentially *is* copying. If your motivation for avoiding making the type "copy" is it's size then you probably need to re-think your overall design.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is that if you remove your `Var` from the shared variable, what would be left there? What happens if any other copy of your `Arc` is left somewhere and it tries to access the now removed object?

There are several possible answers to that question:

##### 1. I'm positively sure there is no other strong reference, this is the last `Arc`. If not, let it panic.

If that is the case, you can use <s>[`Arc::try_unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap)</s>[`Arc::into_inner()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.into_inner) to get to the inner mutex. Then another `into_inner()` to get the real value.

```
//let mutex = Arc::try_unwrap(shared_var).unwrap();
let mutex = Arc::into_inner(shared_var).unwrap();
mutex.into_inner().unwrap()
```

<s>Note that for these `Result::unwrap()` to work your type has to implement `Debug`, for... [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994296/865874). If it does not, you can use a `match/panic!` pair.</s>

##### 2. There may be other strong referenced copies of `Arc`, I want to steal the object anyway.

Then you have to put something in its place. The obvious solution is to store an `Option<Var>` instead and use [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to steal the value:

```
let shared_var = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(Var {})));
/*
  multithreading job
*/
let mut lck = shared_var.lock().unwrap();
lck.take().unwrap()
```

Now, any other use of this shared value has to check the option in case there is a `None` there.

##### 3. There may be other copies of `Arc` but I don't want to deal with the `Option<Var>`.

But you must leave something there! Maybe you can insert a dummy object in its place. If your `Var` implements `Default` you can use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```
let mut lck = shared_var.lock().unwrap();
std::mem::take(&mut *lck)
```

If it does not implement `Default` but you are able to create an empty object cheapily, use [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.replace.html) instead:

```
let mut lck = shared_var.lock().unwrap();
std::mem::replace(&mut *lck, Var{})
```

Comment: There is also the option of using scoped threads, which renders `Arc` unnecessary.

Comment: You can also use `make_mut()` then `try_unwrap()`.

Comment: "Note that for these Result::unwrap() to work your type has to implement Debug, for... reasons. " are you sure? from the answers to the question it seems like it it is type "E" (the error) which needs to implement Debug, not type "T" (the data).

Comment: @plugwash: Well, yes, but if you look at the definition of the function: `pub fn try_unwrap(this: Arc<T>) -> Result<T, Arc<T>>`, the error type is literally `Arc<T>`, and that [implements `Debug` if `T` implements `Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Debug).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: But [`Arc::make_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.make_mut) requires `T` to be `Clone`, and the OP said that the value was too big to copy.

Comment: The latest version of the rust docs now recommends using [`Arc::into_inner()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.into_inner) instead of [`Arc::try_unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap)

Comment: @mpette: Indeed, thanks, updated. This also prevents the weird "cannot unwrap a non-Debug error" issue.